# magento product specific zip code checking

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I am using magento 1.8.1
I am using zip code Check Delivery Details, like to check if delivery service is available at the client area or not and this is general.

this is working fine.

But now I want to do this product specific like some product are avaialble to some are with different delivery details for eg,  xxx product is available to 111111 zip code in 6 days, to 222222 zip code in 2 days , 33333 delivery not available etc.

I want such product specific delivery detail checking.

Can anyone help me to know if such extension is available or not.

or any specific coding for this.

Comment: Did you give a chance to this extension? https://magecomp.com/magento-cod-checker.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your own shipping module to inform whether the product is available for delivery or not.

Check How to create custom shipping module http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-create-custom-shipping-method

Then in function

```
public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
    {
//check your product shipping availability based on your conditions.
// set all the shipping parameter if product shipping is available.
// or set error message to display user
}
```

for any queries reply back.
Thank you